# Apache module missing (mod_session_crypto)

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm using Apache 2.4.23 on MacOs Sierra.

I would like to configure the mod_auth_form module on my server. I've used the basic configuration from apache.org documentation but it's not working, the server won't start, the error I get is:

> Invalid command 'SessionCryptoPassphrase', perhaps misspelled or
>   defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Here is the part of my httpd.conf that is causing this problem:

```
<Location "/dologin.html">
    SetHandler form-login-handler
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation web/login.html
    AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation web/beta/index.html
    AuthFormProvider file
    AuthUserFile /Users/passwords
    AuthType form
    AuthName "Access with form"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
    SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
</Location>
```

After looking in the documentation I understand that the reason might be that I need to load the mod_session_crypto, so I should add that to my config ...

```
LoadModule session_crypto_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_crypto.so
```

... but I don't have the module with my Apache version (I've searched the libexec folder).

Where could I download it and how to install it?

Thanks a lot

Mathieu

Comment: you will need to compile it yourself or get a binary ditribution that includes it, but yes, the error message you showed is when the module that provides that directive is missing/not loaded.

Comment: @ezra-s thanks for your answer. Do you know where I can find the module to compile or the binary distribution. I'm struggling finding it with google? thanks again

Comment: from httpd.apache.org of course